# Having trouble splitting text due to extra commas

Tags: python, string, split

Here are a few examples:

Input

```
Col
"temp, temp2"
"name, inc., name2"
```

Output

```
Col_upd
["temp","temp2]
["name, inc.", "name2]
```

Right now, I'm using:

```
Col_upd.apply(lambda x: [i.lower().strip() for i in x.split(',')])
```

This fails in row 2 in the above example. I'm not sure what alternatives I have in this situation aside from your a dictionary.

Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Updated version is the expected output. Will make that more clear.

Comment: If you know that all of your problematic values are the same, you can start with something along the lines of `"name, inc.".replace(", inc."," inc.")` before you do the split, which would ideally use pandas built-in [str.split()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html)

Comment: What if I don't? Looks like there are a wide variety of instances where this occurs.

Comment: @madsthaks Are the extra commas always in the first part? And do you always have only two parts?

Comment: yes, there are extra parts. its not always two parts.

Answer (score 3):

If we can assume that there's no extra commas in the second part, you can try to use `rsplit()`.

```
Col_upd.apply(lambda x: [i.lower().strip() for i in x.rsplit(',', 1)])
```

`str.rsplit()` lets you specify how many times to split.

Comment: So what if there are more than 2 parts. This is an interesting solution but what would I do when there could be `n` number of splits

Comment: @madsthaks Can you be more specific? Do the additional parts have extra commas? If we can assume that only the first part has extra commas, let `n = the number of parts`, then we can just do `Col_upd.apply(lambda x: [i.lower().strip() for i in x.rsplit(',', n-1)])`

Comment: If we can't assume only the first part has extra commas, then you need to provide some more information about at what condition an extra comma will be added.